# Why OAuth is disabled for Managed VMs?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

I use Google AppEngine and Google Cloud Endpoints on Managed VMs.

I have very simple service like this:

```
public List<DBObject> getCustomers(User user) throws OAuthRequestException {
    authService.check(user);
    DB db = databaseClient.getDb();
    List<DBObject> customers = db.getCollection(Customer.COLLECTION).find().toArray();
    return customers;
}
```

It should receive authenticated user as parameter and check it with my authService, that will throw OAuthRequestException if user is not authorised.

Everything works fine on dev server, but on production (that is on Managed VMs) I receive following error:

```
HTTP ERROR: 500 
Problem accessing /_ah/spi/com.company.api.MyApi.getCustomers. 
Reason: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException: This feature is disabled for Managed VMs.
```

And logs:

```
com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate convertApiResponseRpcErrorToException: 
RPC failed, API=user.GetOAuthUser : FEATURE_DISABLED : This feature is disabled for Managed VMs.
```

Is there any way to avoid this error? And why OAuth is forbidden on Managed VMs?

I definitely can't switch away from Managed VMs, but I also need OAuth to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

As per Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/), Managed VMs is still in its Beta release, hence the "user.GetOAuthUser : FEATURE_DISABLED" error you are getting (may be / or will be) fixed in the future release "or the complete version" of the Managed VMs.